# Deterministic pushdown automata that checks for a specific variable in nesting levels

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I want to define a DPDA based on a set of rules:

one or more uppercase letters **('A'-'Z')** is a formula.
one or more lowercase letters **('a'-'z')** is a formula.
if **X** and **Y** are formulas, then this is a formula: **X** followed by **'&'** followed by **Y**.
if **X** is a formula, then this is a formula: **'μ'** followed by **one or more lowercase letters** followed by **'('** followed by **X** followed by **')'**.
if **X** is a formula, then this is a formula: **'v'** followed by **one or more lowercase letters** followed by **'('** followed by **X** followed by **')'**.`

I have defined my tokens:

**Upper: ‘[A-Z]+’**

**Lower: ‘[a-z]+’**

**Startpar: ‘(‘**

**Stoppar: ‘)’**

**And: ‘&’**

**My: ‘μ’**

**Ny: ’v’**

The dpda cannot have any limits to the nesting levels.
Only one instance of **'μ'** and **'v'** will be in each nested level. And **'μ'** and **'v'** will also alternate between each nested level, for example:  `μ y (ν z (z))` but this will not work  `μ y (μ z (z))`

I was thinking that a smart way to solve it is to implement a way in the DPDA checks if **'μ'** appears (once or multiple times) at the third parenthesis nested level in a string so that it doesnt allow same sign too appears after the nesting level. And also in that case checks if **'v'** would appear (once or multiple times) at the fourth parenthesis nesting level - if that level contains any operators at all. But how would i do this in a DPDA?